# Oracle Baselines to force execution plan

Tags: oracle, baseline

We have a web based application ( Oracle backend ) which has a query which behaves differently between production and QA. Our QA environment has exact copy of production.

The problem has been traced out to the execution plan between the two environments. The QA has a better execution plan compared to proudction. So the obvious step is to somehow force the same execution plan in production.

One of the method available in Oracle 11.2.0 is to use Baselines. However, the application generates the query dynamically based upon the input provided by the end user.

So my question is to how to use Oracle baseline to force production to use same execution plan.

Comment: Do you have any control over how the application generates the query?  For example, can you change the application to use bind variables instead of literals (if that's even an issue)?  Could you add a hint to beginning of the query?

Comment: You can also copy statistics from QA into Prod and lock them. If you use Hibernate you do not have to many options.